# How to include Google Analytics in an RMarkdown generated GitHub Page?

Tags: google-analytics, r-markdown, github-pages

How can I always include the Google Analytics tacking code on my GitHub Pages webpage generated with R Markdown?

I am currently creating a webpage hosted on GitHub Pages using RMarkdown. To create site, I run `rmarkdown::render_site()`. This command will knit all R Markdown documents to create the relevant `.html` files.

However, I want to include Google Analytics on my site. To do this, I need to include a University Analytics tracking code to my property by pasting the JavaScript code in my main `index.html` file. I can easily do this by editing the `index.html` file directly. However, every time I run `rmarkdown::render_site()`, to render the site, it re-knits the `index.Rmd` file, and thus overwrites the `index.html` file, including the Google Analytics code I previously entered directly.

How can I fix this problem and always have my Google Analytics code contained in the page?

Comment: I may misunderstand you, but why dont you include the JS code in your Rmd file?

Comment: Yes that worked! Such a simple solution that I didn't think it would work :) Thank you!

Answer (score 26):

I just figured out how to get this done while trying to add google analytics to my own RMD site on Github Pages.

#### To add Google Analytics code before the  closing `</head>` tag of an html document produced from RMD...

**Step 1:** Create a .html file containing the Google Analytics Script, and save it in the working directory for your site. *(Simply, create new text file, paste script, save "filename.html".*

**Step 2:** Adjust the yaml header of your rmd file to contain the **includes:** & **in_header:** arguments, and reference the .html file containing the tracking code

```
---
title: ""
output: 
  html_document:
    includes:
       in_header: GA_Script.html
---
```

**Step 3:** Adjust yaml headers for each rmd file related to your site so that each page reports back to Google Analytics.

[It is recommended](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1008080?hl=en) that the Google Analytics tracking code be placed before the closing `<\head>` tag in the sites html. The method above will get that done.

If for some reason you want to include it in the body of the html code, you could just include the GA code in the body of the rmd file by pasting it in between an html_preserve command:

```
<!--html_preserve-->

Google Analytics Code Here

<!--/html_preserve-->
```

Comment: good stuff! I'll just add that step 3 is actually not necessary if you put your things into the `_site.yml`.

Comment: Even better! Thanks for sharing.

Comment: @can I add the same GA script to multiple stand-alone self-contained HTML documents? or each HTML document needs a separate script? Preferably, would like to have multiple files, but a single GA account tracking them.

Answer (score 2):

I manually write the header in the same RMarkdown file and simply include the Google Analytics chunk. This header goes immediately after the yaml. Works like a charm.

```
---
title: "XXXXXXXXXX"
author: "XXXXXXXXXXX"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
---

<head>
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=XXXXXXX"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'XXXXXXXXXX');
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: This will create 2 head tags. The standard one, plus the custom one. That is not valid HTML based on W3C specs.The custom one will be inside the body tag. That is also not valid HTML. That is probably why this solution is not more common. However, it seems all modern browsers will still render the code as far as I can tell.