# Problem with Google Analytics Code in RMarkdown head tag using YAML options "includes:" and "in_head"

Tags: html, r, google-analytics, r-markdown, github-pages

I have a github page produced from a rmarkdown script. I want to insert the google tracking code into the header and have [followed the advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376989/how-to-include-google-analytics-in-an-rmarkdown-generated-github-page) without success. I copy my google tacking code into a text file and save it as a .html file. When I include the code:

```
title: "R Notebook"
output:
  html_document:
    include:
      in_header: woo.html
---
```

The google tracking code comes out in the rendered HTML file at the top of the page. When I look at raw the html file, the tracker code is indeed in the opening   but there is a lot of HTML added to the google analytics tracker. How do I convince RMarkdown to just include the tracker code in the head without printing anything on my html file?

Answer (score 2):

I just fixed this problem on my website. Following [the post you linked above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376989/how-to-include-google-analytics-in-an-rmarkdown-generated-github-page), did you create a new Text File when saving the Google Analytics Script?

The way I fixed this issue (very similar to Step #1 in the earlier advice):

1. Open a new 'Text File' in RStudio.
2. Copy and paste Google Analytics Script.
3. Save script as *google_analytics.html* into working directory.
4. Add *google_analytics.html* after `includes: & in_header:` in `_site.yml` file.

I think my problem, at least, had to do with including the content of a full HTML file in my knitted RMarkdown file, as described at the end of this [R Markdown Cookbook chapter](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/include-html.html).